# Authentication in cross-platform mobile app for Active Directory users

Tags: security, authentication, mobile, active-directory, cross-platform

Looking for some ideas on how to authenticate Active Directory users on multiple platform devices (Android, iOS, Windows). Currently reading about [Authenticate users with Azure Mobile Apps or the Active Directory Authentication Library for Cordova](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/cordova-security-auth/).

What are your recommendations and best practice resources?